# Prevent to close Java swing Application

Tags: windows, swing

How to prevent to close Java swing Application, when user clicks on close button?

Comment: Here is a more basic question: If users can't quit your application by closing the window, how are they supposed to quit?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);` on your main frame should prevent that.

The [setDefaultCloseOperation(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) method allows you to choose what to do when the user closes the JFrame:

> - DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE (defined in WindowConstants): Don't do anything;
>     require the program to handle the
>     operation in the windowClosing method
>     of a registered WindowListener object.
> - HIDE_ON_CLOSE (defined in WindowConstants): Automatically hide
>     the frame after invoking any
>     registered WindowListener objects.
> - DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE (defined in WindowConstants): Automatically hide
>     and dispose the frame after invoking
>     any registered WindowListener objects.
> - EXIT_ON_CLOSE (defined in JFrame): Exit the application using the System
>     exit method. Use this only in
>     applications.

Comment: can you give me an example of how can i catch this event when user closes the window? i want to reset some static variable before the frame is disposed, but i can not find information how to do that. As on next reload, the frame acts wrongly because of already set values of those variables

Comment: @Johnydep - You shouldn't really ask questions in comments, but rather as a full [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), so do this next time. Short answer: the JFrame you created is a Window, and you can add a WindowListener.

Comment: OK i'll be careful next time ;)

Comment: This is mainly for a Windows-like system. On Mac you may hit Cmd+Q and  close the application anyways. Maybe it would be better to give a solution in this direction also.

Comment: @FedericoZancan - the question is about preventing the application from closing when a user clicks on the close button, only. Cmd+Q is the same as alt+F4 on Windows systems. Blocking such signals is another topic.

Answer (score 2):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
// handle window closing 
});
```